# Dimension for a closed subspace of $C[0,1]$.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $X \subset C^1[0,1]$ be a closed subspace of $C[0,1]$ (with sup norm).

Prove that $X$ has to be finite-dimensional.

Comment: Please give motivation, background and/or your ideas on how to solve this...

Comment: well, my basic tries were to use baire's theorem and classification of finite subsapaces of banach spaces as ones having all it's subspaces closed but without succes. Ofcourse assumpion that every element of X has continious derivative must be crousial so i was thinking about functional transformating functions from C[0,1] to it's primitive and combinig that with some banach theorems but i can't see if that leads to the solution.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since $V$ is a closed subspace of $C[0,1]$, then it is a Banach space. Let $A : V \to \mathrm{C}[0,1]$ be the operator $Au=u'$. In order to show that $A$ is bounded, it suffices, using [Closed Graph Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_graph_theorem), to show that:

*If $\{u_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}\subset V$ and
$$
u_n\to u \,\,\,\&\,\,\, u_n'\to v, \,\,\, \text{both uniformly on $[0,1]$},
$$
then $u\in \mathrm{C}^1[0,1]$ and $u'=v$.*

Since $V$ is closed subspace, then  $u\in V$, hence $u$ is continuously differentiable and
$$
u_n(x) = u_n(0)+\int_0^x u_n'(t)\,dt \,\to\, u(0)+\int_0^x v(t)\,dt=u(x),
$$
as $n\to\infty$, due to the uniform convergence of the
sequence $\{u_n^\prime\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$.

Meanwhile, $u(x) = u(0)+\int_0^x u'(t)\,dt$, and thus $v=u'$.

The boundedness of $A$ implies that there exists a $c>0$, such that
$$
\|u'\|\le c\|u\|,  \tag{$\star$}
$$
for all $u\in V$, where $\|\cdot\|$ is the norm of $\mathrm{C}[0,1]$. Inequality ($\star$) implies that the closed unit ball of $V$:
$$
B_1 \,=\, \{u\in V: \|u\|\le 1\},
$$
is equicontinuous, i.e., for every $u\in B_1$ and $x,y\in[0,1]$,
$$
|u(x)-u(y)| \,=\, \Big|\int_x^y u'(t)\,dt\,\Big| \,\le\, c|x-y|,
$$
and by virtue of [Lemma Arzelà–Ascoli](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arzel%C3%A0%E2%80%93Ascoli_theorem), $B_1$ is compact. Hence $V$ is locally compact. But is a Banach space (more generally, a topological vector space) is locally compact, then it has finite dimension.

Comment: If a Banach space is compact, then it is zero-dimensional. ;) You probably meant to write "locally compact".

Comment: @tomasz: Corrected it.

Comment: One could even simplify the first part of the proof by considering $T : V \to C^1, f \mapsto f$. Here, closedness is more obvious.