# Every closed subspace of ${\scr C}^0[a,b]$ of continuously differentiable functions must have finite dimension.

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

If $F \subset {\scr C}^1[a,b] \subset {\scr C}^0[a,b]$, then $\dim F < +\infty,$ where $F$ is a closed subspace (in $ {\scr C}^0[a,b]$). I found [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/935580/dimension-for-a-closed-subspace-of-c0-1), which is very good and solves the problem, but how can we prove the assertion without using Ascoli-Arzelà in the end? We didn't cover equicontinuity, etc.

Is there a more elementary proof of the result?

Comment: You might specify whether "closed" means closed in $C([a,b])$ or closed in $C^1([a,b])$.

Comment: Closed in $ {\scr C}^0[a,b]$. I should have been more clear, I added it in the question now..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The inclusion $\mathscr{C}^1[a,b] \hookrightarrow \mathscr{C}^0[a,b]$ is continuous, so $F$ is also closed in $\mathscr{C}^1[a,b]$. Thus $F$ is a Banach space with respect to the $\mathscr{C}^0$-norm and with respect to the $\mathscr{C}^1$-norm. Hence these two norms are equivalent on $F$ (since they are comparable). Say we have

$$\lVert f\rVert_{\mathscr{C}^1} \leqslant K\cdot \lVert f\rVert_{\mathscr{C}^0}\tag{1}$$

for all $f\in F$.

Let $n > K\cdot (b-a)$. Consider the subspace

$$F_n = \Bigl\{ f \in F : f\bigl(a + k\tfrac{b-a}{n}\bigr) = 0,\text{ for } 0 \leqslant k \leqslant n\Bigr\}.$$

$F_n$ is the null space of a (continuous) linear map $F \to\mathbb{C}^{n+1}$, hence $F_n$ has finite codimension ($\leqslant n+1$) in $F$.

Suppose $F_n \neq \{0\}$, i.e. there were an $f \in F_n$ with $\lVert f\rVert_{\mathscr{C}^0} = 1$. Say the maximal modulus $1$ is attained at $t\in [a,b]$. The distance from $t$ to the next point $a + k\frac{b-a}{n}$ is at most $\frac{b-a}{2n}$. By the mean value theorem, we therefore have

$$\lvert f'(x)\rvert \geqslant \frac{2n}{b-a} > 2K$$

for some $x\in [a,b]$, but that means

$$\lVert f\rVert_{\mathscr{C}^1} > 2K \lVert f\rVert_{\mathscr{C}^0}.$$

This contradicts $(1)$, hence there is no $f \in F_n$ with $\lVert f\rVert_{\mathscr{C}^0} = 1$, i.e. $F_n = \{0\}$, and consequently $\dim F \leqslant n+1$.

Comment: thanks! Can you just clarify a couple of things for me, please? If you call $\Phi_k: F \to \Bbb C$, by $\Phi_k(f) = f(a+ k \frac{k(b-a)}{n})$, then $F_n = \bigcap_{k=0}^n \ker \Phi_k$? The map is not so obvious to me.. and I don't see how the codomain is $\Bbb C^{n+1}$ and not $\Bbb C^n$. And you're using that if $\Phi$ is the single map (that I didn't saw), then: $$\dim F \leq \dim \ker \Phi + n+1,$$so proving that $\dim \ker \Phi = \{0\}$ gives $\dim F \leq n+1 < +\infty$ as wanted, right?

Comment: AH, nevermind, I think I got it.. the map $\Phi: F \to \Bbb C^{n+1}$ is: $$\Phi(f) = (f(a), f(a + \frac{b-a}{n}), f(a+ 2\frac{b-a}{n}),\cdots, f(b)).$$

Nevertheless, if you can confirm that I got it all right... `:)`

Comment: You got it right, $\Phi$ is the evaluation at the $n+1$ points $a + k\frac{b-a}{n},\, 0 \leqslant k \leqslant n$. And the rank formula says $\dim F = \dim \ker \Phi + \dim \operatorname{im} \Phi$. And of course $\ker \Phi = \bigcap\limits_{k = 0}^n \ker \Phi_k$.

Comment: Ok. Thanks again!