# Verify a Subset of $C[0,1]$ that is also closed as a subset of $L^2[0,1]$ Is Finite Dim

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-verification

I'm working on the following question in Royden:

> Let $X$ be a linear subspace of $C[0,1]$ that is closed as a subset of $L^2[0,1]$. Verify the following assertions to show that $X$ has finite dimension. Suppose the sequence $(f_n)$ belongs to $X$.
>
> 1. Show that $X$ is a closed subspace of $C[0,1]$
> 2. Show that there is a constance $M \geq 0$ such that for all $f \in X$ we have $\|f\|_2\leq \|f\|_{\infty}$ and $\|f\|_{\infty} \leq M\|f\|_2$
> 3. Show that for each $y\in [0,1]$, there is a function $k_y$ in $L^2$ such that for each $f \in X$ we have $f(y) = \int_0^1k_y(x)f(x) dx$.

My Attempts and Questions:

1. Assuming $C[0,1]$ has the sup norm, then any sequence in a linear subspace will, in fact have a limit in $C[0,1]$, because continuous functions over a compact set are uniformly continuous and a limit of such functions is also uniformly continuous in the sup metric.
2. $\|f\|_2\leq \|f\|_{\infty}$ amounts to pulling the max out of the integral. The other direction I adopted [this argument](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1615193/subspaces-of-c-alpha-0-1-are-finite-dimensional-if-closed-in-c0-1).
3. I'm not sure how to tackle this. Any ideas?

Comment: Riesz representation theorem.

Comment: I was able to use the theorem and the hypothesis after thinking about the wiki. But we haven't covered this in class yet. Is there another way to see this? The exercise is in the section where they introduce Hahn-Banach.

Comment: You need in fact Hahn-Banach to extend the evaluation functional $f\mapsto f(y)$ from $X$ to $L^2$. But I do not see how to avoid Riesz.

Comment: wait I'm confused. why do we need anything about extension? We have $f(y) = \int_0^1k_y(x)f(x) dx$ for any $f \in C[0,1]$. Riesz gives us a functional $\int_0^1k_y(x)* dx$ that operates on $f \in C[0,1]$. I think I'm missing some understanding of what the question is asking itself -- I don't understand what the role of $y$ is in this question either.

Comment: For fixed $y$ the evaluation map at $y$ is a continuous linear functional on $C[0,1]$ (without representation as a Riemann or Lebesgue integral!), hence the restriction to $X$ is a continuous linear functional with respect to the sup-norm and thus, by the second statement in the exercise, also w.r.t. the $L^2$-norm. By Hahn-Banach there are continuous linear extensions to $L^2$ which, by Riesz, can be represented as integrals.

Comment: thanks! almost there -- in order to use hahn-banach though, don't I have to show theres a functional which is subadditive and homogenous which dominates $f  \rightarrow f(y)$ on $L^2$? How does statement 2 help?

Comment: Denoting the evaluation by $\delta_y$ you have $|\delta_y(f)|\le \|f\|_\infty\le M\|f\|_2$ for all $f\in X$, i.e., $M\|\cdot\|_2$ is a domonating sublinear functional.

Comment: One more thing (Sorry!): the Reisz representation associates continuous functions and measures. So does the $L^2$ extension associate $L^2$ functions and measures?

Comment: There are two Riesz theorems describing the duals of Hilbert spaces and of continuous functions. Here you need the former.